# Make use of web fragments (Servlet API 3.0) in a huge project environment

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-3.0

We recently migrated to Servlet API 3.0. Since we are developing a framework which sometimes needs a few changes in the `web.xml`, projects which are based on our framework need to update their `web.xml` whenever a change in the framework is made.

Servlet API 3.0 introduces the new *Web Fragments*, which make this behaviour more loosely coupled and dynamic. I create a `web-fragment.xml` and move all our stuff from the web.xml in there. So the projects now have only to define the following `web.xml` and their own additional declarations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
   version="3.0"
   metadata-complete="false"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

We have to use `metadata-complete="false"` to enable the Fragment search in JARs (our framework has the `web-fragment.xml` in `META-INF/`.

Since we have many dependencies to other frameworks and libraries (about 80-90) and the `metadata-complete="false"` also triggers searching for Annotations it takes up to unacceptable **12 seconds** to search through all libraries.

The mechanism as it is works great and I like the fact that we are more decoupled from our framework, but the startup time is fatal! Also we have to increase the available memory for Tomcat from `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` to `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m` to get it started without getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` (caused by the inefficiently implemented annotation processor of the Tomcat (about 50.000 classes are cached)).

---

*I know that we can disable the annotation search within a library, but as we use mostly third-party which don't have the `metadata-complete="true"` flag, this also isn't an option.*

**Can we do anything to disable the search for annotations? Or can we force the Servlet Container to only search in declared libraries for the `web-fragment.xml`?**

I would really like to use the new web fragment feature, but with the increased startup time and memory this isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable annotation processing by configuration for certain JAR files. I used it for JAR files only, it may not work for exploded `WAR`s. Look at `<tomcat>/conf/catalina.properties`, line 76 (Tomcat 7.0.22):

```
# List of JAR files that should not be scanned for configuration information
# such as web fragments, TLD files etc. It must be a comma separated list of
# JAR file names.
# The JARs listed below include:
# - Tomcat Bootstrap JARs
# - Tomcat API JARs
# - Catalina JARs
# - Jasper JARs
# - Tomcat JARs
# - Common non-Tomcat JARs
# - Sun JDK JARs
# - Apple JDK JARs
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution, thank you! Unfortunately this would be a servlet container dependent solution. We target to run on every servlet container, so this solution isn't a good choice for us.

Comment: @codevour How have you solved your problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

There are some system properties in Tomcat that enable controlling JAR scanning since 7.0.30. Check the doc page [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#JAR_Scanning).

Basically these ones are:

- `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip`
- `org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip`
- `org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip`

Not sure what is the earliest time you may set them, maybe `ContextListener`?